# Why the image disappear when participating in the Facebook note builder you select the link to the image through Meta Code

Tags: php, facebook, share

when i share a link from my website on facebook , i don't find Image which i selected to desperate to other users [image: when share facebook link i dosnt see]

```
<meta property="og:image:height" content="240">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="440">
```

Comment: `http://pouchpoint.com/story_news.php?id=307754359396047` – that is not an image, it’s a complete HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

I got a permission error (403) when i try to access that image directly. That´s the reason why it doesn´t show. After fixing that, refresh the Open Graph tags in the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Edit: Your og:image is not an image at all. It must be an absolute URL to a picture.

Comment: i change orgenal  image link in this example 
the correct is `<meta property="og:image" content="http://pouchpoint.com/story_news.php?id=307754359396047" />`